# How to get parameter value from url durandal

Tags: javascript, durandal, single-page-application, singlepage

In Durandal, I have map router

```
router.map([
    { route: 'tickets/:id',      moduleId: 'tickets/thread', nav: true }    
]).buildNavigationModel();
```

I have link in address bar

```
http://localhost:8083/#tickets/ticket001
```

In my `viewModel`, how can i get the value of `id`?

Comment: How did you navigate to ticket001 at first place? I assume you've passed that id. Haven't you?

Comment: @AdelSal: `window.location.href = '#tickets/ticket01';` <-- `ticket001` is an `id`

Answer (score 3):

You can also get them via the activate function on your view model.  All parameters in the router will be passed as arguments to your activate function.  see the "Route Parameters and Query Strings" section in the router docs:

http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-The-Router.html

Comment: I have found that the args are passed as strings (which makes sense) but that is not picked up when using TypeScript. So despite having an arg declared as a `number`, the value is a string. Fun times.

Answer (score 2):

I found the anwers, use route plugin:

```
define(['knockout', 'plugins/router'],
function (ko, router) {
    return {
        param = router.activeInstruction().params[0]
    };
});
```

Comment: Using ```router.activeInstruction().queryParams``` is better and more consistent. Because if you use querystring on multiple pages after each other, the query params can be on ```params[1]```